# What is the filesystem UUID?

Tags: linux, filesystems

What is the filesystem UUID?
I want to know how filesystem UUID is used.

For example, if duplicate UUID in xfs, mounting is failed.

```
$ dmesg | tail
[345633.687773] XFS (sdc): Filesystem has duplicate UUID 4e6fb31f-a2c4-45a1-8502-63fdc0fd42e0 - can't mount
...
```

Should UUID duplication be avoided on other filesystems(e.g. ext4, btrfs, etc...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.linux.com/news/what-uuids-can-do-you/) is a useful article explaining what UUID is and the problems it solves. In a nutshell, it's a `universally unique identifier` which allows administrators to distinguish between multiple filesystems in a Linux machine.

> Should UUID duplication be avoided on other filesystems(e.g. ext4,
>   btrfs, etc...)?

Yes, `UUID`'s should be unique, no matter what the filesystem type is.

For `XFS`, the following command can be used to regenerate the UUID of an XFS filesystem:

```
xfs_admin -U generate /dev/sdc
```

Running this command should show you the new UUID. Edit `/etc/fstab`, then you should be good to go.

Comment: I see. I understand now. Thank you!